# C# Struct to delphi packed record

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I have a function extracted from a delphi dll

```
function func_name(par1: Byte; par2: struct1) : boolean
```

Struct 1 is made up of :

```
struct1 = packed record
    Number: Byte;
    arrStr : array[1..8] of struct2;
end
```

Moreover struct2 is made up of:

```
struct2 = packed record
    Code: Byte;
    Price: Single;
end
```

Now using C# i am trying to pass a same time of structure to delphi using the following

First i created my structures:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct struct2
{
    public byte code;
    public Single price;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct struct1
{
    public byte Number;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    public struct2[] Prices;

    public struct1(int elements)
    {
        Number = 0;
        arrStr = new struct2[elements];
    }
}
```

Note `elements` is always 8.

So when i try to run the code thus filling the array and passing it to the function i get the following error:

`Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Array fields must be paired with ByValArray or SafeArray)."`

Comment: @Jerry No there are not

Comment: @David that's why I deleted my comment immediately when I saw your answer (seconds after I posted it). I just remember many similar cases which were fixed by not using "packed" records and just using plain records.

Comment: @Jerry What matters is that both sides match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is inline in the struct. It is not a pointer. So instead of

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
```

you must use

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
```

Comment: Great job! It worked just fine! I tried byValArray but didn't define the size! Thanks again!

Comment: FWIW the docs say: *When the MarshalAsAttribute.Value property is set to ByValArray, the SizeConst field must be set to indicate the number of elements in the array. The ArraySubType field can optionally contain the UnmanagedType of the array elements when it is necessary to differentiate among string types. You can use this UnmanagedType only on an array that whose elements appear as fields in a structure.* You can ignore the grammar snafu in the final sentence!!